# Jupyter note book not executing properly

Tags: python-3.x, function, jupyter-notebook, arguments, return-value

Hello i've been having some issues with jupyter notebook lately and am wondering if anyone knows why.

I'll sometimes have the program not execute and it'll have this symbol [*] so ill restart the kernal. Then it executes. However sometimes it wont produce the correct execution even though the code is correct. so I'll restart the kernel and clear my outputs. That usually fixes it. Now i'm working on this problem where i ask the user to answer a math problem if their input sum is correct it will say congrats if wrong it will say they got it incorrect. The program  initially kept saying that user_answer was not defined. Then it didn't give me an error at all but would skip over the if statement and just print out the else: statement even if the answer given by the user was correct. is it my code? or is it the editor i'm using and if so how can i make it execute properly. I'm trying to learn python and i'm finding this a bit frustrating because i don't know if its my code or the editor half the time.

Here's my code:

```
import random

number_1 = random.randint(1,250)
number_2 = random.randint(1,250)

def main():
    ask_question()
    check_answer(user_answer)

def ask_question():
    user_answer = int( input( "What is " +\ 
               str(number_1 )+ ' + ' +\
               str( number_2 ) + '? '))
    return user_answer

def check_answer( user_answer ):

    correct_answer = number_1 + number_2

    if user_answer == correct_answer:
        print("Congratulations", user_answer, +\
              "is correct!")
    else:
        print("Sorry that is not correct the" +\
              " answer should be", correct_answer)

main()

outputs:

**most common one**
What is 126 + 250? 8 (enter)
---------------------------------------------------- 
-----------------------
NameError                                 Traceback 
(most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-99955f4e983a> in <module>
     29               " answer should be", 
correct_answer)
     30 
---> 31 main()
     32 

<ipython-input-2-99955f4e983a> in main()
      6 def main():
      7     ask_question()
----> 8     check_answer(user_answer)
      9 
     10 def ask_question():
NameError: name 'user_answer' is not defined

OR

I'll get this and i didn't change anything in my 
code..

What is 126 + 250? 376 (enter)
Sorry that is not correct the answer should be 376
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main function of your code is slightly wrong.

```
def main():
    ask_question()
    check_answer(user_answer)
```

In the check_answer function, replace user_answer with the number that the user enters. So, assign a variable to the ask_question function, which is then put into the check_answer function.

```
def main():
    user_answer = ask_question()
    check_answer(user_answer)
```

Also, it is not a good idea to mix local variables (variables that are inside functions) and global variables (variables that are outside functions). in your case, you are calling global variables (number_1 and number_2) inside the check_answer function, which is not good python. 
A better way of creating this code would be to have only one function which chooses two random numbers, asks for the user answer and verifies if it is correct or not.

I was unable to reproduce the other error (of the answer being wrong).

Comment: is there a rule of thumb of when you should use multiple functions? Because i did this as a practice problem and the person i was following split it up into 3 functions. in fact i copied his code to make sure i was doing it right and it still seemed to fail. so i made it more simple by just using 1 and it works fine now. I'm sure in the future i can't just create one function for it all.

Comment: There is no hard and fast rule, but you should use one function for one task. It varies from programmer to programmer, and also on what your function is trying to achieve. If you wish to learn more about programming best practices, I recommend reading Clean Code by Robert Cecil Martin. The book is based on Java but it is useful for python as well.

Comment: Also, if your issue has been resolved, please mark it as answered. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the feed back. I'll look into the book. Also how do i mark it as answered.. i'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: I am not sure myself (also new to the website!), but there should be an option next to the answer.